# How do you do binary file I/O with Win32 ASM?

Tags: file-io, assembly

How would I do file io in assembly? And I mean assembly. I hate macros. I'm looking to edit a pre-existing 10 MB file with ASM.

If someone could give me some quick example code on how to do it, that would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

All the actual file I/O is going to be handled by the OS, abstracted away by the `open()`/`close()`/`read()`/`write()`/etc. system calls (or whatever the equivalents are on Windows).  So really all your ASM needs to do is call out to these functions (correctly setting up arguments on the stack, etc.), and handling return values.

So if you already know how to use `open()`/`close()` etc. in C, and you know how to call a function from ASM, then you're done!

Comment: Thanks. I already figured as much. I'm really just looking for someone providing a quick example ASM code on how to do this.

Comment: @TheRoll: an example of what? How to call a function?

Comment: Examples of calling file IO functions, aye.

Answer (score 3):

While reading a file certainly should not be your first program if you're learning assembly [Here's](http://win32assembly.online.fr/tut12.html) an example. As long as you're in Windows, you'll need to somehow invoke [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the win32 API.

The example calls CreateFile using macros, don't let that stop you, you can easily open the nasm include files and look at the assembly behind the macros and copy paste that assembly.

Comment: Isn't Iczelion the one who starts his ASM tutorial by assuming you're familiar with assemblers?

Comment: Anyway, I'm going for file io because I learn by doing and I prefer to do things that are practical. That's why I'm starting with a basic program to binary edit some stuff for me.

Comment: I guess I'll stick to compiling from a high level language into ASM and reading that when I want to learn some code. I'm quickly getting the impression SO is the wrong place to be looking for help with assembly - there don't seem to be many, if any, assembly coders here.

Comment: I was posting because I figured I could get a nice and quick answer here, but at this rate I think it's faster if I just look it up myself this way.

Comment: @The Roll: There are plenty of people who know ASM here, but you won't find many people who do this sort of thing in ASM (i.e. specifically invoking file I/O from ASM), because there's no need for it, and frankly, it's grim!

Comment: Then I gather they're not ASM coders but people who use ASM to supplement whatever it is they do code.

Comment: @The Roll: Yes, because there's no reason (other than self-education) to use ASM for anything other than tight inner loops, or *extremely* low-level code on microcontrollers, etc.

Comment: I assume I can take your opinion to be representative of the SO community at large. That, then, highlights my problem in coming here.

Comment: @TheRoll: your problem is that you don't know as much as you think you know. You're  being told the truth, but are too ignorant to recognize it. Almost nobody uses assembler for file I/O. There is no value in doing so in 99.99 percent of all cases.

Comment: John Saunders, I find that it is often the ignorant who are eager to presume what is not of value and thus dictate how others should act.

Comment: @TheRoll: in this case, not so much. I could post an example of buffered I/O in DEC-10 Assembler for you, so you'd understand why we stopped doing that sort of thing decades ago.

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but I'm not sure that would do me much good. My entire goal here is to get a good feel for coding in assembly and understanding how these things are really done, but I'm moving on to different resources than SO discussions now.

Comment: @The Roll Goodbye, Farewell, and Amen

Comment: @The Roll: It's not so much my opinion, as it is an actual fact.  No-one writes assembler nowadays unless they have no choice (i.e. no compiler available), or they need to optimise a hot-spot.  Handling file I/O is probably neither of these, so you won't find a great deal of people who've spent any time thinking about file I/O in ASM.  What's more, as I said in my answer, this is nothing more than the intersection of file I/O in C and function-calling in ASM.  Learn either of those and you're 50% of the way there.